# Java 8 filter List by highest values of each id

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Is there a way to do the following with java 8 features and lambdas?

I have this class

```
public class A{
    private String id;
    private int version;
    // getters...
}
```

Input (the list is ordered by id and versions ascending):

```
[{"1",1},{"1",2},{"2",1},{"2",2}]
```

I want to have a List with the highest versions of each id, so the result should look like:

```
[{"1",2},{"2",2}]
```

I already have a solution but I dont like it that much. I figured maybe there is a better way with java 8.

```
static List<A> removeOldVersions(List<A> aList) {
    Map<String, A> map = new HashMap<>();
    aList.forEach(a -> map.put(a.getId(), a));
    return (List<A>) map.values();
}
```

Comment: So what's your code that doesn't work?

Comment: Please note that such questions result in more positive feedback when you include your attempts. You see, there are many existing questions very similar to your request. Have you tried to research this topic yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could collect to a `Map` and merge entries via `BinaryOperator.maxBy`. Once that is computed call `values` on it (that will return a `Collection<A>`):

```
  yourList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              A::getId,
              Function.identity(),
              BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(A::getVersion))))
        .values()
```

Comment: I was try to find a solution with `groupingBy`, but so far the closest thing I managed to produce was a `Map<String,Optional<GroupA>>`. +1

Comment: @Eran I assume that was `groupingBy(..., Collectors.maxBy...)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Introduction

There are two approaches to this, both of them use `Comparators`, I suggest you read more about them at the following link:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

I would like to show you my most simple approach without writing your own filter/distinct alghorytm. This solution will use the Stream API of Java 8.

(Let's say you are using an `ArrayList` or `HashSet` in both examples.)

## Using Streams

```
public class Sorter {

    private final class A {
        private String id;
        private int version;

        private A(String id, int version) {
            this.id = id;
            this.version = version;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getVersion() {
            return version;
        }
    }

    public void sort() {
        final ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<A>() {{
            add(new A("1", 1));
            add(new A("1", 2));
            add(new A("2", 1));
            add(new A("2", 2));
        }};

        //Using List as we want to be sure that our List is in order
        list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.version)).filter(distinctByKey(a -> a.id)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, Object> keyExtractor)
    {
        Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        return t -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(t), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
    }

}
```

Hopefully this has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add each pair to a `Map`, checking if it already exists and has a lower value before overwriting.

Classic approach:

```
{
    List<A> in = Arrays.asList(new A("'1'", 1),
                               new A("'1'", 2),
                               new A("'2'", 1),
                               new A("'2'", 2));

    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>(in.size()); // 'Linked' just keeps the original ordering
    for (A element : in) {
        @Nullable Integer version = map.get(element.id);
        if (version == null || version < element.version)
            map.put(element.id, element.version);
    }

    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Output:

`{'1'=2, '2'=2}`